# how to read env variables of docker-compose file and package.json file from github action?

Tags: github, docker-compose, environment-variables, github-actions, building-github-actions

from my docker-compose file I have to read an env variable. locally, I can read that variable like this: `ENV_FILE=.env docker-compose -f docker-compose.dev.prisma.yml up --build` 
but as .env file is in .gitignore, GitHub action can't get that file. how can I read them?

almost same issue in my package.json file. I have need some env variables to be read from npm scripts:

```
"start:backend": "wait-port $API_HOST:API_PORT && yarn start"
```

what I have tried is added those variables in secrets of github, but it didn't get those variables. though expect those 2 files, envs are read perfectly from github action.

Answer (score 8):

Try creating your env file manually as a step in your workflow and pass in your repository secrets. Your docker-compose and package.json should be able to read your environment variables:

```
    - name: create env file
      run: |
        touch .env
        echo VARIABLE=${{ secrets.VARIABLE }} >> .env
```

Comment: what about multiple variable?
{{secrets.variable}} is only one variable

Comment: chain another echo cmd

Comment: Thanks a Lot for the response and the comments. Worked very well for me in github actions